# Is Redis 2.2.x documentation available somewhere? (Specifically LRU strategy)

Tags: redis, documentation

I'm trying to find out information about my version of redis, which is `2.2.7`. I've found the old git repository but unfortunately hardly any documentation was part of the repository.

I desperately want to find out if I can use any sort of LRU strategy with Redis 2.2.x. Long story on why I can't experiment on my version of it.

On their website or while web browsing I can't find it anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire documentation for Redis is managed in this Git repository: https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc/commits/master

Although the repository doesn't have version tags, you could go back in the commits and search for the details you're missing.

As for your question about LRU in v2.2 - according the config file of v2.2  (https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.2/redis.conf#L200-L205) both `volatile-lru` and `allkey-lru` are supported for `maxmemory-eviction`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @jQwierdy happy I could help - feel free to reach out with anything Redis, I have fair connections in that domain. Also, stop using 2.2.7 it is long ripe.

Comment: I just created another question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577834/redis-using-config-set-on-the-fly-in-a-master-slave-relationship), it should be a quick answer for someone as knowledgable as you :-)