# Redis - Using CONFIG SET on the fly in a master slave relationship

Tags: redis

I'm looking to change the `maxmemory` amount and the `maxmemory-policy` to `allkeys-lru` while the server is running based [on this](https://redis.io/topics/config). I'm going to do this first via:

```
$ redis-cli
> SET CONFIG maxmemory xxxxxxxxx
> SET CONFIG maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Then after seeing that it works in an expected way, i.e. evicts keys until it's size drops to `xxxxxxxxx` bytes, I will change the config file. When we are running this in a master slave configuration, is there any issues that can occur based on the order I change this config in the master and the slave?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about 2.2.7? Hard to tell but could work. Test it, but if it fails... Upgrade :)

Comment: Hey @itamarhaber, I did it and it works, kind of. The thing I'm finding is that we really just have some key leak's i.e keys that should have been deleted long ago. Is there another way of saying, delete the LRU 3 GB of keys instead of actually setting `maxmemory` 3gb Lower?

Comment: AFAIK LRU in Redis was always approximated, so some inaccuracies are totally possible. I don't know of a way to forcibly evict LRU-style, but you can always cherry-delete keys.

Comment: We have an unholy number of keys, so it won't really work. We are in the tens of GBs for redis.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. Perhaps rdb-tools works with that version... You can identify the keys that you don't need and script a deletion. Regardless, you really need to upgrade your Redis version and do some data housekeeping.